# Summation of product of all pairs of array elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm

If an array has [10,20,30,40]. I need to calculate  10 *20+10*30+10*40+20*30+20*40+30*40.
Assuming that both multiplication and addition take constant time.
Is it possible to evaluate it using O(n)?

Comment: `sumprod(lst)
{
    sum=0;
    prod=0;
    foreach(x in lst)
    {
        sum+=x;
    }
    for(x in lst)
    {
        sum-=x;
        prod+=sum*x;
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

```
def sumproductsofpairs(lst):
    total = 0
    psum = 0
    for x in lst:
        total += psum * x
        psum += x
    return total
```

Comment: If the range is specified, eg. `l=2` and `r=1000000000` and we need to calculate the sum of pairwise product of the elements for 100000 such cases, what can a more efficient solution using some data structure or some generalized formula?

Comment: @taurus05 [Formula](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BSum%5Bi*j%2C%7Bj%2Ci%2B1%2Cr%7D%5D%2C%7Bi%2Cl%2Cr%7D%5D)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this . Can you share some links which can teach me how to derive such formulas.

Comment: @taurus05 If I were doing this by hand (I almost never do any more), then the steps would be a) recognize that the answer will be a multivariate polynomial of degree 4 b) derive this polynomial somehow. The blunt object that works in all situations is polynomial interpolation on sufficiently many values, but it's easier to do inclusion-exclusion here.

Comment: Thanks for your instant feedback. I strongly believe i still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:
sum of product of all pairs=((sum of numbers)-(sum of square of numbers)^2))/2

```
int arr[4]={10,20,30,40};
int sum=0,sum_sq=0;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    sum+=arr[i];
    sum_sq+=(int)pow(arr[i],2);
}
cout<< ((int)pow(sum,2)-sum_sq)/2;
```

Output:

```
3500
```